# Getting an error when creating a conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I try to make a conda environment for my tensorflow code but when i try it says: `CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting.`

```
C:\Users\waabe>conda create -m tensor python=3.6

CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting.
```

I was watching a tutorial made by Tech With Tim and for him it worked.

Could you help me?

Comment: It should be `-n` not `-m`

Answer (score 2):

The command is like:

```sh
$ conda create -n tensor python=3.6
```

Reference: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands